# entering a serial number into a textbox and displaying a msgbox if the num is already used

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i have a text box where the user must enter a serial number i want the system to display a message box telling " number already exists" if the number entered by the user is already there in the MySql table called "customers". how do i achieve this in vb 2010?

Comment: are you using datatables.?

Answer (score 0):

Call the procedure from your code and put the output into a `DataTable`. You can then loop through the values which you would compare to the user imput and set a matched flag if the entered value matches one within the `DataTable`. You then want to return a relevant message, probably within an `IF` statement using the matched flag as your statement.

Now you have the basic steps, I'm pretty sure you could find how to do all of the above on Google. It is too much for someone to knock up and post as an asnwer I'm afraid.

Comment: Dim SerialNumberExists As Boolean
        SerialNumberExists = Select * from customers where sino =(" + serialno.text + ") ' you write the implementation
        If SerialNumberExists Then
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The serial number already exists!", _
                "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)                                                          will this code work?

Comment: Personally I don't write a select like this, i tend to use a stored procedure and get a dataset back as it is more secure. But it's down to personal preference I suppose. I have no idea if this code will work, give it a run?

Comment: i dont know how to use a stored procedure and dataset

Comment: In that case use your method, its just a suggestion.